# Is it normal practice or very bad to nest maps?

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

Is it normal practice or very bad to nest maps several levels?

```
        // name property     // name singal         // interval of Ranges      // values

typedef std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::map<RangeSignalValue, std::string > > > sgHashSignals;
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with that, but a few more typedefs might make it easier to read.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've certainly done this. However, I'd break down the definition into digestible chunks:

```
typedef std::map<RangeSignalValue, std::string> RangeIntervalMap; 
typedef std::map<std::string, RangeIntervalMap> NameSignalMap;
typedef std::map<std::string, NameSignalMap>    NamePropertyMap;
```

Comment: +1 for actually writing out the `typedef`s while I was still trying to remember the syntax! ;)

Answer (score 2):

If it makes sense in the context you're working in then I don't see any problems, other than it might be hard to read. Might it be possible to use `typedef` to make some of these nested maps easier to understand?

Answer (score 1):

For instance:

```
typedef std::map<RangeSignalValue, std::string> RangesValues;

typedef std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, RangesValues > > sgHashSignals;
```

Answer (score 0):

The biggest issue is that lookup is slightly slower than the alternative:

```
           // property+signal, concatenated // interval of Ranges    // values

typedef std::map<std::string, std::map<RangeSignalValue, std::string > > sgHashSignals;
```

Precisely how you should concatenate the first two strings depends on their syntax, though.

This replaces two string lookups by one. The downside is that it takes more memory.

Comment: Are you sure? Lookup in maps with string keys needs string comparisons. If these strings have a common prefix, lookup will have to always iterate at least over the prefix's characters. That's O(N), while map lookup is O(log N). I'd say this depends on the data you have.

Comment: It's far from given that your suggestion is faster.  It depends on a lot
of factors (including the implementation).  I'd go with the most natural
solution (which is probably nested maps), and experiment both if I have
a performance problem.

Comment: @sbi Not to mention that duplicating the first key for every instance of the second key could use a lot more memory.  And maybe ruin locality.